# How to sort by increasing order an array of objects based on its properties - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, object

I'm having some problem in sorting an array of objects:

```
class Genome {

var id: Float?
var won: Float?
var lost: Float?
var drew: Float?

var fitness: Int = Int.random(in: 0...100)

init(id: Float, won: Float, lost: Float, drew: Float) {
    self.id = id
    self.won = won
    self.lost = won
    self.drew = drew
  }
}
```

This is the object.
I have an array of 50 "Genome" objects and I need to sort it using its fitness property.

I already tried this:

```
genomes.sorted({ $0.fitness > $1.fitness })
```

But it didn't work.
How can I do that?

Comment: did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) has a return value. You have to declare a new variable and **in**creasing order is `<`

```
let sortedGenomes = genomes.sorted{ $0.fitness < $1.fitness }
```

To sort `genomes` in place use [`sort`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort)

```
genomes.sort{ $0.fitness < $1.fitness }
```

Side note: Don't declare properties as optional which are initialized with non-optional values.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 & Swift 4 & Swift 5**

This will sort your object array in ascending order.

```
let sortedGenomes = genomes.sorted(by: { $0.fitness < $1.fitness })
```